# Scroll para SpriteKit

Tags: swift2

Estoy haciendo un juego con Swift, y tengo una imagen gigante en un `SKSpriteNode` que es el mapa (similar a la imagen que adjunto) y cada punto es un `SKSpriteNode` hijo, estoy haciendo el scroll de esta manera en la función `touchesMoved`:

```
let newLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
let prevLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
var newYPosition = map.position.y
if (newLocation.y > prevLocation.y) { newYPosition = map.position.y + abs(newLocation.y - prevLocation.y) }
else if newLocation.y < prevLocation.y { newYPosition = map.position.y - abs(newLocation.y - prevLocation.y) }
if newYPosition <= 0 && newYPosition > self.frame.height - map.frame.height{ map.position.y = newYPosition }
```

Pero al hacerlo de esta forma el scroll es lento, no tiene el efecto que se detiene lento cuando lo suelto, si no que se detiene de inmediato cuando saco el dedo. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para tener algo más similar a un scroll real?

[image: Mapa]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí esta la respuesta:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/96822/sprite-kit-tutorial-drag-drop-sprites

Cuando levanto el dedo lento, entonces se detiene el scroll, pero cuando levanto el dedo rápido el scroll avanza un poco más y se detiene un poco más adelante.